# Request.Params.AllKeys[0] sometimes null

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a strange problem, randomly my webmethod will return null values for Request.Params.AllKeys[0], if I refresh the page and attempt it again it will work.

Basically what I'm doing is I have a canvas that I submit to a webmethod like this:

```
function convertCanvas(strType) {

            if (strType == "PNG") {
                if (ValidateForm('form1')) {
                    //var oImg = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, true);
                    //var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    var canvasData = document.getElementById("panel").toDataURL("image/png");
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", "/Job/SignatureSave", true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", canvasData.length);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", "<%: Model.RequestMV.RequestID %>");

                    // subscribe to this event before you send your request.
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            //alert the user that a response now exists in the responseText property.
                            if (xhr.responseText == 'yes') {
                                window.location.reload(true);
                                //OnSubmitForm();
                            }
                            else {
                                alert('Saving signature failed, please try again');
                            }
                            // And to view in firebug
                            console.log('xhr', xhr.responseText)
                            console.log('data:', canvasData)
                        }
                    }

                    xhr.send(canvasData);
                }
            }
        }
```

I know that canvasData does contain data even when it alerts to show that signature did not save as I have canvasData in an alert on each post and there is always data even when the webmethod returns failure.

My webmethod is like this:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string SignatureSave(string data)        
    {
        try
        {
            var b = Request.Params.AllKeys[0];
            var filename = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];

            string imageAsBase64 = b.ToString();
            string fileName = filename.ToString();

            imageAsBase64 = imageAsBase64.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            imageAsBase64 = imageAsBase64.Replace(" ", "+");

            int remainder = imageAsBase64.Length % 4;

            for (int i = 4; i > remainder; i--)
            {
                imageAsBase64 = imageAsBase64 + "=";
            }

            string imagestring = imageAsBase64;


            byte[] imageAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagestring);

            var saveToFileLoc = Path.Combine(@"" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignaturePath"].ToString(), fileName + ".png");

            // save the file.
            var fileStream = new FileStream(saveToFileLoc, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fileStream.Write(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length);
            fileStream.Close();

            return "yes";

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "no";
        }   


    }
```

Why on the javascript side is the data there and being sent in the request, but on the codebehind side it sometimes, not all the times, only sometimes says the first element of params is null?

Comment: maybe sometimes it's send without parameters? sometimes maybe the data doesn't agree with your parameters

Comment: But why would it not attach the canvas data one minute but another it will attach the canvas data as a parameter.  Very odd how I have to refresh the page and draw again then it will maybe attach the data to the postback and other times it won't.  There is no consistent pattern that I can debug.